# Adding a font to a docker image

Tags: google-app-engine, docker, fonts

My company has a docker image which we use for app engine flex. I need to add a font, and there doesn't seem to be a simple apt package anywhere, so I need to add it manually, following steps like the ones listed [here](https://www.google.com/get/noto/help/install/) for command-line installation on Linux. Here's what I have so far:

```
FROM gcr.io/google_appengine/python

# ...

# Copy the font to the appropriate location.
# The font is in a ttf in the same directory as the Dockerfile.
RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto
COPY NotoColorEmoji.ttf /usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto
RUN chmod 644 /usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto/*

# Rebuild the font cache.
RUN fc-cache -fv
```

As you can see, the image is based on the GAE base python image. We're adding a few other things, as well, but this is the stuff relevant to the font.

The `fc-cache` output when building the image makes it clear that it is detecting one font in the noto directory:

```
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
```

And when I log in to a container, I see that the file was indeed copied. I can even run `fc-cache` again manually and see that same output. The new font, however, is never reflected in `fc-list`.

It's been frustrating to diagnose this because following similar steps seems to work perfectly on my own machine. It's almost as if `fc-cache` is behaving differently in the container.

Any ideas on what I might be missing?

**Update:**

I added a line to the docker file to explicitly set the correct permissions on the font file after copying it, but it made no difference. This was expected because these commands ultimately run as root, but still it seems like a better practice.

Interestingly, though, I tried this with a different font (NotoEmoji-Regular.ttf) and it *did* work. I'll be looking into what the difference between these two fonts might be that is causing this.

Very frustrating.

**Another Update:**

It seems the primary difference is likely the colors in the font, which is nonstandard in the TrueType format. As comments have pointed out, my system is using a newer version of fontconfig than the docker image, which likely accounts for the discrepancy.

I'd like to verify this, but it's digging a bit down a rabbit hole that my organization would rather me not spend too much more time on. If anybody is able to do so, however I'd be happy to give you the accepted answer. Otherwise I'm going to have to leave this be for a bit.

Comment: I understand there are issues like https://github.com/docker/hub-feedback/issues/1375, but just in case, could you follow https://github.com/KWARC/localmh/issues/217 (done from a Dockerfile) and see if the end result (the image) does include the expected font?

Comment: Could it be because of the size? It seems rest all the fonts are less than a MB and this one is 5MB+ ?

Comment: This may not be a docker issue but the environment of `fc` version issue. I tested on Ubuntu 16.04 docker and i get `fc-list` to work fine. The `fc-list -V
fontconfig version 2.11.94`. But for `debian 8` and `debian 9` the version is `2.11.0`. Now it may be possible this is a bug in `fc` itself or one of the dependencies

Comment: @TarunLalwani I've got the same version discrepancy. That very well may be it, especially since the font in question is a color font and thus nonstandard in TrueType. Ultimately I'm just going to go with the non-color font in this case, but when I have time I'll see if I can update fc on the image.

Comment: I tried compiling `fc` from source but there were just too many dependencies to be satisfied and lot less info on compiling them

Comment: Is hosting your font in cloud storage an option? It sort of sounds to me like you might be setting yourself up for un-needed headache by trying to bundle it with your application.

Comment: Yeah, that would be better. The situation is pretty complicated, however, so it may or may not be an option.

Comment: Thanks @TarunLalwani . Your right, ubuntu 16.04 seems to work fine but I tried debian jessie as a base image and it does not correctly install the fonts I was using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's the font file had issue, check the report in image[image]

Comment: Yeah, I imagine these are coming from a compatibility problem due to the use of colors in the font. The more I read about this font, the less I'm surprised by this. It helps to actually see it in the log, though, so thank you!

Comment: As per this github link https://github.com/googlei18n/noto-emoji/issues/200  , this seems to be a known issue by the community. Not sure if it will be addressed soon though.

Answer (score 5):

Try to add to dockerfile

```
# install fontconfig
RUN apt-get update; apt-get install -y fontconfig

# refresh system font cache
RUN fc-cache -f -v
```

Answer (score 0):

I used below commnad inside Docker file to install fonts and that worked for me.

```
RUN apt update && apt install fonts-indic -y \
    && fc-cache -f
```

or

```
RUN apk add font-noto-gujarati font-noto-kannada font-noto-avestan font-noto-osage font-noto-kayahli font-noto-oriya font-noto-telugu font-noto-tamil font-noto-bengali font-noto-malayalam font-noto-arabic font-noto-extra \
    && fc-cache -f
```

Note: u can add more fonts name based on your requirement.